# How to send a signal to a function in embedded c

Tags: c, embedded, signals

I have a wireless device and can send commands from my phone to the device. A command executes a bunch of steps to complete an action. At the moment, this action function is blocking, ie until the call completes the user needs to wait, with no option to quit. If for any reason, the call doesn't complete then the user is stuck with that screen. A simple pseudo looks like this:

```
do_action() 
{
    int result = 0;
    result |= step_a();
    result |= step_b();
    result |= step_c();
    result |= step_d();
    return result;
}
```

How can I make this process "interruptible", ie use a signal/flag to tell this function call that the user has terminated and that this action needs to be terminated/cleaned up. Is there a way I can "time bound" this function, ie exit the action if not completed within expected time? How can I implement such a feature? One of the issues also is that some of the steps, such as step_a, step_b functions are blackbox functions, ie implemented by the manufacturer and are blocking and I have no way modify their interface.

Comment: If you can modify `do_action`, have it "pet the dog" in between steps. Also spin out another thread before taking any of those steps, monitor the state of the watch-dog.  When the watch-dog times out, terminate the process.

Comment: So, I make a thread that will monitor the time each step takes, and may be also checks for user input? I think I can do that

Comment: If all code is written by you, then you have to re-think the design so that every loop that takes time and is essentially blocking, has the possibility to poll an "abort" variable each lap in the loop. That is, the further down in the functions you can implement it, the better and faster it will get. And the earlier you consider this in the program design, the less messy the work-around will be.

Comment: That makes sense. I have control over the do_action() function, but not all the intermediate steps. Modifying those means pulling out the guts of software I don't have enough knowledge about.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to see if the API has a way to pass a timeout to individual calls (or ask the manufacturer to implement one). If this is possible, then you could structure your code to take one step, check if you should quit (timeout reached or user interrupted), then take another step.

Should you be stuck with blocking vendor code you cannot modify, you will need to put something in place that can terminate an in-progress "action". Exactly what this interruption can be will depend environment is running on your device.

If your device is running more feature complete operating system then you could either add a second thread to your process that monitors the first (lookup pthreads), or you could execute your action in one process and have a separate monitor process that kills the first if it takes too long or if the user cancels the action (lookup the "fork" and "kill" system calls).

If your code is running on a more bare-bones environment then your options are more limited. One way to do this is to manually set up a hardware timer and an interrupt handler to check state. The specifics of how to do this will depend entirely on what hardware you are using.

Comment: At the very least, I am thinking of checking the user state(terminated or not) after each step and cleanup/bail out if such an event was recorded. I think your idea of a monitor thread to check for user input and or timeout is also something i can implement